# Why is ping.exe is using all my CPU?

Tags: windows, ping

I use Windows XP Professional, with Norton anti-virus.

A few days ago I spent some time reviewing the services running under `svchost` as this was hogging the CPU, using Process Explorer.  Seemed to work a treat.

Today I've noticed `ping.exe` is using up to 100% of CPU – and the computer is so slow. I have tried stopping it using Task Manager and both stopping and suspending it in Process Explorer, but it just keeps restarting.

I have found the "application" file in `C:\Windows\System32` but can't find a program to uninstall it. Does anyone know if `ping` is associated with any of Windows XP's services?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds pretty fishy! "ping" is just a command line utility available in just about every OS under the sun. Strange that it would be chewing up your CPU. Are you able to find the path from where the services is running? [Grab this guy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) it can show you the path to where the executable is. It might be interesting to trace it. Then grab malwarebytes and give your machine a scan to make sure it is clean. To be extra safe, run hitman pro as well!

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed a problem with the same symptoms at my friend's.

Not sure if your specific cause is the same, but for him running [TDSSKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208280684) (removes several variants of malware from the Rootkit.Win32.TDSS family) did the trick.

Comment: hehe, hello there :)  I just dealt with the same problem in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

It surely is a virus. Immediately run an antivirus AND any good anti-spyware software.
Such utilities make your system act as zombies and generate attacks from your system on other websites or they can steal every bit of information from your system.